# When during the slug build process does my rails app have access to the ENV variables set by Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am looking to load a file into my rails cache with a cache key based on any of the possible values set by the Heroku Labs: Dyno Metadata addon (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata).

Within that article, I am looking for a unique identifier which is available early within the slug build process.

`HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT:       2015-04-02T18:00:42Z
HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION:          v42
HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT:              2c3a0b24069af49b3de35b8e8c26765c1dba9ff0`

These are the three that are of some interest to me (example data above). During my asset pre-compilation step, I am dependent on a unique value which I have decided to use any of the 3 above. This step is done before my rails app is operational.

Initially I tried `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION` however I noticed that it is not set until the slug build process is completed which means during my asset pre-compilation step, it is `nil`.

I am then trying `HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT` to see if this is known before asset pre-compilation. Is this correct? From some initial testing, it seems to work correctly (it is at least known before asset pre-compilation), however I would like to know the correct order that these are set.

If this is not an earlier value that is available within `ENV[]`, what would be a better suggestion?

====== UPDATE:

I have been playing around with the configuration below with the values:

`HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT:       2015-04-02T18:00:42Z
HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION:          v42
HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT:              2c3a0b24069af49b3de35b8e8c26765c1dba9ff0`

I have noticed that before building the assets, those above values do not change pre-build but rather post-build. Below, I have the resulting output below. As you can see, the current deploy is `2583508` but `ENV['HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT']` returns `8318914` during the build process until the application has finished, then `ENV['HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT']` is updated to `2583508`.

```
=== sample-app Releases - Current: v356
v356  Deploy 2583508   email@gmail.com    2017/04/26 20:05:51 -0400 (~ 40s ago)
v355  Deploy 8318914   email@gmail.com    2017/04/26 19:51:33 -0400 (~ 14m ago)
v354  Deploy c054f1e   email@gmail.com    2017/04/26 19:40:42 -0400 (~ 25m ago)

BROWSER RESTRICTIONS SLUG COMMIT: 83189141e4e45643bf71d9aa78604e479ea210f1
```

Is there a way to uniquely know the current build before actually building? Maybe not using the heroku lab addon?

Answer (score 5):

I have received a response from Heroku support which seems to fix the needs that I am looking for.

Heroku's response:

> Unfortunately, at this point, our dyno metadata lab flags and the
>   config vars made available during the build don't entirely match up.
>   During the build, you can use the SOURCE_VERSION environment variable,
>   which will be the commit hash. Then, at runtime, you can use
>   HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT to get the same value.
>
> The reason behind this difference is mostly a difference of context.
>   Naming that variable HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT during build wouldn't make
>   sense, as it's not a slug yet.
>
> Since we will never set both config vars, you should be able to use
>   any of them, and fallback to the other if it's not set.

My current implementation now is:
`ENV["SOURCE_VERSION"] || ENV['HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT']` in that order. This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this for myself by using a deploy script and using the heroku-cli tool to update my app with the new commit hash before pushing the code:

deploy.sh

```
...
heroku config:set APP_VERSION=<commit hash> --app <your app name>
git push heroku master
...
```